# Handle .inc files as PHP

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

Can somebody tell me how to treat `.inc` files as `.php` so I can include the .inc files into my php code. You can tell me change their extension to `.php` but it is not easy since there are hundred of pages which use the inc version.

Basically I need to declare types and handler in .htaccess.

I am running PHP over Apache.

Thanks.

Comment: You want them viewable in the browser? PHP can include them without Apache knowing what they are.

Comment: It's a good idea partly so that Apache won't just show the source code (which can be an issue; .inc files often contain config stuff, like DB connection info).  Though why people don't just name them with .php is beyond me.

Comment: @cHao Better yet, that's why I have those sorts of files (actually, almost all PHP files) outside the webroot entirely.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are including them via `include()` or `require()` into your PHP code, there's no need to change the extension.  Anything included via the `include()` family is already treated as PHP.

**Addendum:**

Please also see @Darhazer's answer configuring Apache to serve `.inc` as PHP if you have a need to do so. (It's not totally clear from your question).

Comment: @Micheal: I've tried it without the handler and it didn't work. I have not yet tried with the handler tho. I'll see then.

Comment: You know what, It just worked without adding the handler. I was dealing with wrong peace of code. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 10):

add this to your httpd.conf

`<FilesMatch "\.inc$">

    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php

</FilesMatch>`

Or in the .htaccess file
`AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .inc`

Answer (score 1):

Do nothing.

PHP doesn't care what file extension included files has, it will still execute any code between `<?php` and `?>` in them.

Comment: This is incorrect as the web server needs to pass the file to be interpreted by PHP.  Without an appropriate handler it won't - the raw php source code will appear.

Comment: @davidgo — I said **included** files. The webserver doesn't matter once you get to that point.